# How to reading .txt file and rewriting by adding space after specific position / index for each line in python

Tags: python, text-files, readline

I want to read .txt file and add space after a specific position/index for each line. please consider below example for more details.

suppose my file contains

`12345 678 91011 12 1314`

In the above file, the first row contains space after a specific position/index [4] , then after position/index[8], after position/index[14] and after position/index[17]

Expected output : 
I want every row in the file is having space after a specific position. i.e for the first row, I want to add space after index [2], then add space after index [6], then add space after index[11], then add space after index [21], and so on...

`123 45 6 78 91 011 12 131 4`

As a reminder, I don't want to replace elements but add a new space after a specific position/index.

reading .txt file and add space after a specific position/index, for each line in python.

```
with open("C:/path-to-file/file.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.read().split("\n")
    newlines = []
    for line in lines:
        line = line.rstrip()
        newline = line[:] + ' ' + line[:]   # this line is incorrect
        newlines.append(newline)
    with open("C:/path-to-file/file.txt", "w") as newfile:  
        newfile.write("\n".join(newlines)
```

add space after a specific position/index for each line a text  file

suppose my file contains :

`12345 678 91 011 12 1314`

Expected output :

`123 45 6 78 91 011 12 131 4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

```py
space_indecies = [2, 5, 8]

with open("C:/path-to-file/file.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.read().split("\n")
newlines = []
for line in lines:
    line = line.rstrip()
    for n, i in enumerate(space_indecies):
        line = line[:i + n] + ' ' + line[n + i:]
    newlines.append(line)
with open("C:/path-to-file/file.txt", "w") as newfile:  
    newfile.write("\n".join(newlines))
```

The `i + n` is needed, because the index where you want to insert your space shifts with every space inserted

Comment: please, Can you write the entire code , because this syntax error appears: "unexpected EOF while parsing"!

Comment: Done. Give it a try now!

Comment: This error appeared : line = line.rstrip() : invalid syntax !

Comment: That is because I've left in the old solution. Removed.

Comment: When you run the code there is no errors, but the file is not executed!

Comment: `print newlines` before you write it to the file.See if it was processed correctly, and it's the writing that's not working, or if it's the processing

Comment: The error is by typing the Write statement in the file, the code was processed correctly, can you write it but the same results.

Comment: Try the modified code after the edit. Instead of opening a file inside the scope of an other file, it drops the scope of the first file, and opens a new one.

Comment: I tried it, it was done correctly, I am very grateful to you and your cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using generator expressions.

If you are happy to provide the list of indices *after* each space rather than *before*, this will do the job:

```
line = '12345 678 91011 12 1314'
idx = [3, 7, 12, 22]
' '.join([line[i:j] for i, j in zip([None]+idx, idx+[None])])
```

which gives `'123 45 6 78 91 011 12 131 4'`.

Otherwise you would need to first add one to each index:

```
idx = [2, 6, 11, 21]
idx = [i+1 for i in idx]
```

Comment: please, Can you write the full code because this syntax error appears: "unexpected EOF while parsing"!

Comment: You probably copied the `>>>`, which I removed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I deleted it and this error continues, please, write the full code and run it to see the error.