# why not rewrite the text in the file .txt file , even though the code was processed correctly?

Tags: python, readlines

When the code is run, it executes correctly and no errors appear, and the results are expected, but the file is not "overwritten". What is the solution?

Rewrite the file even though the code is correct and there are no errors!

```py
space_indecies = [2, 5, 8]

with open("data.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.read().split("\n")
    newlines = []
    for line in lines:
        line = line.rstrip()
        for n, i in enumerate(space_indecies):
            line = line[:i + n] + ' ' + line[n + i:]
        newlines.append(line)
    with open("data.txt", "w") as newfile: # Maybe wrong with this sentence
        newfile.write("\n".join(newlines))
```

expected result : 
If there is an error in the writing statement inside the file, please modify it correctly, with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

```
newlines = []
with open("data.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.read().split("\n")
    for line in lines:
        line = line.rstrip()
        for n, i in enumerate(space_indecies):
            line = line[:i + n] + ' ' + line[n + i:]
        newlines.append(line)
with open("data.txt", "w") as newfile:# Maybe wrong with this sentence
    newfile.write("\n".join(newlines))
```

Comment: Gives unexpected results ! i found the answered , thx.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57727283/how-to-reading-txt-file-and-rewriting-by-adding-space-after-specific-position